# What happened to Mr. Blue after he was infected in The Incredible Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

In *The Incredible Hulk*, Mr. Blue became infected with Hulk's blood just after Abomination was created. Also, Mr. Blue's head started to show some kind of mutation. What happened to him?

What troubles me: What was the point of showing the infection and mutation? Has he become something notable that Marvel Cinematic Universe has yet to show? Anything from comics?

Comment: “What was the point of showing the infection and mutation?” Planting a seed for possible future development. Not everything pans out when you’re making a series of interconnected movies over the course of ten years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character referred to in the Incredible Hulk film as 'Mr Blue' (e.g. Dr. Samuel Sterns) is referred to elsewhere in the Marvel Comic canon as "[The Leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_%28comics%29#In_other_media)", a super-intelligent megalomaniac with an

> 'oversized brain housed in a towering cranium, often portrayed as the Hulk's nemesis'

[image]

Focusing on the film canon, a [recent interview](http://www.mtv.com/news/1597802/incredible-hulk-producer-wants-to-make-a-sequel-which-could-include-edward-norton/) with 'Incredible Hulk' Producer Gale Anne Hurd has indicated that the decision to include a scene in which Professor Stern's forehead is infected with Banner's blood was a deliberate decision to pay homage to the Marvel villain (to which she owns the rights). She goes on to say that she is hopeful that the original character actor, Tim Blake Nelson will return to play **The Leader** in the upcoming Hulk 2 sequel;

> “The Leader,” she said when asked what Nelson was transforming into
>   when last we saw him. “It would be a blast [to put The Leader in the
>   sequel], and Tim Blake Nelson is tremendous and a very talented
>   filmmaker in his own right.”
>
> “When I think of all the many, many, many villains in the Hulk
>   universe, we’ve now done the Abomination, so wouldn’t it be great to
>   tackle the Leader?” she beamed. “It’s a completely different type of
>   cerebral villain, which would give the movie a terrific new take on
>   the character.”

Comment: Getting Tim Blake Nelson to come back to play The Leader in Hulk 2 just got a bit more murky as it was just announced two weeks ago that he's going to play Moleman (or the pre-change version of him) in that new Fantastic Four reboot.

Comment: @krillgar - That's not really a barrier. Don't forget that Affleck (Daredevil) is fronting the new Batman film and Chris Evans (Johnny Storm) is fronting the new Captain America films.

Comment: I do agree with that point. I think it all depends on when Hulk 2 comes out. If they come out close to each other, schedules might conflict. My trepidation is just that it's not a straight ahead as without him being in another movie.

Comment: This answer and these comments aged badly.